# Having Three Different Speeds from location.getSpeed()

Tags: java, android, locationmanager

I have the following code:

```
private LocationManager _locMgr;
public static String speed_1;
public static String speed_2;
public static String speed_3;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

_locMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
_locMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 2, this);
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
speed_1 = String.valueOf(location.getSpeed());
Thread.sleep(1500);//delay
speed_2 = String.valueOf(location.getSpeed()));
Thread.sleep(1500);
speed_3 = String.valueOf(location.getSpeed()));

//then viewing the three different speeds
}
```

The problem is, when i view the three speeds i get them all the same, i need to get 3 different speeds in the current call of onLocationChanged() method

Please help.

Comment: Kindly read this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685842/android-gps-location-speed-unreliable

Comment: `location` is value object and won't be changed over time. It is gps fix for some specific moment of time. Location manager will call onLocationChanged three times with three different values if you specified update criteria correctly

Comment: @EugenMartynov so i guess i have to do the following: to get the speeds at different calls of onLocationChanged, when finishes it'll return the different speeds.